# How does the chainsaw trick at the end of "The Clue of the Savant's Thumb" work?

Tags: jonathan-creek

At the end of [The Clue of the Savant's Thumb](http://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/b01rqchz) Jonathan Creek, using a specially constructed chainsaw, appears to cut straight through Joey Ross (Sheridan Smith) at the waist, while she in fact remains completely unharmed.

Is this an actual magic trick? If so how does this trick work?

Answer (score 2):

Pretty much everything you would ever need to know is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sawing_a_woman_in_half).

As to the specific trick shown it is a variation on the 'Jigsaw' or Bow Saw' method. Basically the saw blade is not as solid as it seems.

Comment: Please include the relevant parts of the article in your answer so it's not a "link only answer"